Wix use Dropdown with CMS date time
I cannot connect my Dropbox to a CMS entry value of datetime. I want to make form where you can pick a date from a list defined in a CMS collection. The date type is simply greyed out in Wix.
I figured I could use Wix CMS Expressions to format the date to the text field but that is simply not possible.
What can I do? What are my options?
I tried connecting the CMS to the dropdown but cannot select a field of type date.

You can query for all the dates and then programmatically populate them into the dropdown. (You could also use a datepicker element where only some dates are enabled for choosing.)
The code would look something like this (where the CMS collection is named Events and the date field's key is date):
import wixData from 'wix-data'

$w.onReady(async function () {
    const { items } = await wixData.query('Events').find()
    $w('#dropdown').options = items.map((item) => ({
        value: item.date,
        label: item.date
    }))
})

If need be, you can format the date before populating it into the dropdown. Probably best to do that using standard JavaScript date formatting functions.
